# Groovy how to find a value in a map using regex

Tags: java, groovy

I have a map that is like this:

```
map[:]
map['subject'] = 'math'
map['subject'] = 'science'
map['subject'] = 'english'
map['location'] = 'building b'
map['address'] = 'some street'
```

and a regex that look like this

```
def regex =~'math|science'
```

so I need to use the regex to find all the values that are not math or science and create a JSON object. I have use map.findAll but it is not working when I do:

```
map.findAll{it.value == regex}
```

I get:

```
[:]
```

the end result should be

```
map['subject'] = 'english'
map['location'] = 'building b'
map['address'] = 'some street'
```

Comment: when i use map.findAll {it.value == regex} I get [:]

Comment: The posted code defining the map doesn't make any sense, you're just assigning a new value to the key 'subject' repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of `map[:]` the line should be

```
map = [:]
```

Second, defining a key repeatedly doesn't make sense here, you're just overwriting the same value. It looks like you need multiple maps, like this;

```
map1 = [subject: 'math', location : 'building z', address: '1 street']
map2 = [subject : 'science', location : 'building y', address : '2  street']
map3 = [subject : 'english', location : 'building b', address : 'some street']
```

Add the maps to a list:

```
def maps = [map1, map2, map3]
```

Then you can use `~=` to compare the text you want to match to a regex:

```
maps.findAll { it['subject'] =~ '^(math|science)' }
```

The output is a list of maps that match the criteria passed to findAll:

```
[[subject:english, location:building b, address:some street]]
```

Comment: I don't think that code does what you think it does.  You have `map['subject'] = 'math'` followed by `map['subject'] = 'science'` followed by `map['subject'] = 'English'`.  After all of that, `'math'` and `'science'` aren't even in the `Map` because you used the same key for all 3 of those values.